# How to get Functions Parameters Number in C

Tags: c

How can I get a Function Parameters Number?
If i write wrong number of Parameters in a function call, gcc return an error. Somehow GCC "counts" the number of Parameters. How can I get that value? (Fixed number of arguments!).
Example (GETPARNUMBER - any function or Macro or else that returns the number of Parameters):

```
// Init
void MyFunction(int iPar1, int iPar2, int iPar3)
{
     // Do Something
}

void main(void)
{
     printf("\n\r Number of Parameters: %d\n\r", GETPARNUM(MyFunction));
}

// End
```

"GETPARNUMBER" should return 3:
"Number of Parameters: 3"

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want that? maybe there is  another way of achieving what you want.

Comment: [Compilers can do things that C programs are not allowed to do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quod_licet_Iovi,_non_licet_bovi). This is one of them.

Comment: You can know the amount of parameters a function needs by looking at the function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

There is no such meta-information stored about functions. Remember that when a program is compiled, most human-readable data (such as function and variable names) is removed, at runtime that information is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not directly in your program.

You could use something like [CodeWorker](http://codeworker.free.fr/) in order to **parse** your C code (what the compiler does) along a BNF (= "code grammar" rules). You can write your own, short, simplified BNF to encompass only function declarations and count parameters, and with CodeWorker provide an ouput that could tell you:

```
Found 1 function declaration in MyFile.c:

1: void MyFunction with 3 parameters:
   - iPar1 int
   - iPar2 int
   - iPar3 int
```

---

You could also try a doc-generator, which would tell you how much and what parameters you need for each functions.

---

Lastly, you could write a parser yourself to parse your C files and find out how many params each function needs.

---

This all depends on ***why*** you want to programatically count your parameters...

Answer (score 0):

So "This is not possible", I have to do it the hard way. The ideia is to declare a const array with "&function" and the "number of parameters" to make sequencial calls through that function pointers array. To avoid forget functions update in the array (if I change some function), I thought maybe there is some kind of macro to declare the number of parameters.

Thanks to all.